# Minecraft replace command syntax error

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am using minecraft bedrock on my switch.
All I want to do is to remove all the oak trees so am using the fill/replace command but all I get back is `syntax error: unexpected "minecraft:log": at "05 94 -41 >>minecraft:log<<"`
I have no clue what it means,

My starting point is `-891, 60, 409` and my end point is `-305, 94, -41`

The exact thing I am typing in is:

```
/fill -891 60 409 -305 94 -41 minecraft:log replace minecraft:air
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: When you want to show an MC command in your post, skip a line and indent four spaces. It makes your commands easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Java Edition, Bedrock Edition doesn't accept namespace identifiers in its data values. You also need to provide the `tileData` value before `replace`.

You'll have better luck without the namespace and including the tile data:

```
fill -891 60 409 -305 94 -41 log 0 replace air
```

Comment: That command shouldn’t work, try it. It’s missing the data value.

Comment: Yep, looks good to me :D

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the data value before “replace.”

```
/fill -891 60 409 -305 94 -41 minecraft:log 0 replace minecraft:air
```

Comment: Last time I checked, namespace values (`minecraft:`) weren't accepted. Is this still true?

Comment: Ill test it in a bit, i thought they were but i guess im not sure

Answer (score -1):

No minecraft just log and also
Maybe you should do a specific log like oak_log

Comment: The ID `oak_log` does not exist here